# Concatenating text and string in Field Calculator expression (python)

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, arcmap, field-calculator

I'm trying to copy an attribute value from one field to another (sum of raster values), but I'm having issues in writing a functioning expression for a Calculate Field script.  I'm adding a field called `SUM` and trying to copy the value from the field `"SUM_" + filename[0:-4]`. I have multiple files I am trying to do this on and the field names are different in each, which is why it is being written in this manner.

Here's the code I have so far:

```
for table in arcpy.ListTables():
    arcpy.AddField_management(table, "SUM", "DOUBLE")
    expression = ["SUM_" + str(filename[0:-4])]
    arcpy.CalculateField_management(table, "SUM", expression, "VB")
```

This doesn't work as I receive the following error:

```
File "C:\Users\kellyj\Desktop\Projects\CostAnalysis\Route_Cost_Analysis.py", line 82, in <module>
    arcpy.CalculateField_management(table, "SUM", expressionvalue, "VB")
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.2\arcpy\arcpy\management.py", line 3354, in CalculateField
    raise e
RuntimeError: Object: Error in executing tool
```

Any thoughts as to how I can fix this?

Comment: Thanks @Aaron. The script now finishes without an error, but the new "SUM" field is 0 in all of the shapefiles. Am I pointing to the source field properly in the expression?

Comment: Your script is creating the SUM field as a numeric Double field and then trying to calculate a string into it.  Numeric fields cannot have non-numeric strings calculated into them.  The SUM field has to be a string with enough characters to hold the concatenated "SUM_" plus the longest base file name.

Comment: The reason Aaron's code produced 0 is that the input was without any delimiters and was interpreted as a variable.  An uninitialized variable would be interpreted as 0.

Comment: Use expression = "[SUM_" + str(filename[0:-4]) + "]" to make a field name inside a string.  When interpreted by the Field Calculator the string from Python is just a field name, not a string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to have a square bracket surrounding the "SUM_" thing

Trying change

```
expression = ["SUM_" + str(filename[0:-4])]
```

to

```
expression = "[SUM_{0}]".format(str(filename[0:-4]))
```

Answer (score 2):

The brackets have to be inside the string, since otherwise the brackets will create a Python list.  When Python passes a string that has brackets inside of it as the expression, Python does not interpret the brackets, but the Field Calculator interprets the bracketed expression within the string as a field name.  Use the code that follows:

```
for table in arcpy.ListTables():
    arcpy.AddField_management(table, "SUM", "DOUBLE")
    expression = "[SUM_{0}]".format(str(filename[0:-4]))
    arcpy.CalculateField_management(table, "SUM", expression, "VB")
```

Comment: you are right, I tought that he wanted a string, not the field value.